# get dynamically inserted script as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I'm using an extension that allows you to write javascript and then register it to a site, which then dynamically injects this script into the site and effectively allows you to modify the DOM locally when the site is loaded up.

This is fine, however, I want to implement script updating. This would be fine if I could give the script tag an Id or even a class, but I can't. So what I need to do is somehow get the current script tags content as text (without JQuery selectors). I know how i'm going to do the rest of it though.

I had a look at `document.currentScript` but it's returning null. I had a quick google and this happens when it's not executing a script, but it must be if it's telling me it's null! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So you basically want to extract all the html `script` tags from the page and get their contents (code) as text?

Comment: and update them back into scripts?

Comment: No, I want to get the current script contents as text. And thanks for the quick reply @AkshayKhandelwal

Comment: Only the current one @Slayther

Comment: But how can you distinguish the current script besides the code that you type? What extension are you using? Tampermonkey?

Comment: @Slayther it's called TamperMonkey. And that's why I'm asking this question, there's no way to get it apart from document.currentScript, and that isn't even a proper element

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you mean by current script? Do you mean the script that is currently running in the browser or the script from TamperMonkey that is currently running?

Comment: The current script tag that the code is executing. The script that will have the DOM modifiers in.

Comment: Ok, so you are asking for the script that you created that is currently running

Comment: I feel there are 2 things that you need to consider here. 1. Inline script and  2. External Scripts.

Comment: And not sure the running script can be captured or not.

Comment: Do you really need to update a script tag? I doubt that would help you anyways. If you just update contents of script tag, it won't execute again.

Comment: If it is an inline script, you can get it using .innerHTML()

Comment: @Slayther I don't mean update the script tag contents, I know it wouldn't, I mean to check my git server to see if the most recent script is different to the current script, and if it is, warn the user that the script needs updating (which needs user confirmation).

Comment: @SinanGuclu Please read the question properly, I can't use any element identifiers

Comment: @RhysO So is it the only script tag? Alternatively is it always in the same position among other script tags? You could use someting like `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[document.getElementsByTagName('script').length-1]` if it is always the last.

Comment: @SinanGuclu No it's not as it turns out, I just tried using `$('script:last').text()` and it returned the one already on the page, not the injected one...

Comment: @RhysO Okay, how are you injecting the script? I have used jQuerys getScript() before and that appends it within the <head>, so it would be worth checking the DOM in the browser before and after the script is injected. Can you share any code?

Comment: @SinanGuclu Yep, the code can be found [here](http://www.gitlab.com/roconnor/ETrackCleanUp). TamperMonkey injects the script for me, so I don't know

Comment: @RhysO Sorry that link gives 404

Comment: Please explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TamperMonkey actually has an inbuilt update operation, which by default checks for updates daily and updates the scripts. To use this, you just need to add this into the userscript headers:

```
// @updateURL    This is the same URL as below, as far as I can tell
// @downloadURL  URL to download the update from
// @version      This is a number, but it needs to be updated with each release for it to be updated
```

My original solution wouldn't have worked anyway, as it required doing an Ajax call to gitlab, which doesn't have a CORS header...